# Why does this python code hang on import/compile but work in the shell?

Tags: python, shell, compilation, sftp

I'm trying to use python to sftp a file, and the code works great in the interactive shell -- even pasting it in all at once.

When I try to import the file (just to compile it), the code hangs with no exceptions or obvious errors.

How do I get the code to compile, or does someone have working code that accomplishes sftp by some other method?

This code hangs right at the ssh.connect() statement:

```
""" ProblemDemo.py
    Chopped down from the paramiko demo file.

    This code works in the shell but hangs when I try to import it!
"""
from time           import sleep
import os

import paramiko


sOutputFilename     = "redacted.htm"  #-- The payload file

hostname    = "redacted.com"
####-- WARNING!  Embedded passwords!  Remove ASAP.
sUsername   = "redacted"
sPassword   = "redacted"
sTargetDir  = "redacted"

#-- Get host key, if we know one.
hostkeytype = None
hostkey     = None
host_keys   = {}
try:
    host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
except IOError:
    try:
        # try ~/ssh/ too, because windows can't have a folder named ~/.ssh/
        host_keys = paramiko.util.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/ssh/known_hosts'))
    except IOError:
        print '*** Unable to open host keys file'
        host_keys = {}

if host_keys.has_key(hostname):
    hostkeytype = host_keys[hostname].keys()[0]
    hostkey     = host_keys[hostname][hostkeytype]
    print 'Using host key of type %s' % hostkeytype


ssh     = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))

ssh.connect(username=sUsername, password=sPassword, hostkey=hostkey)

sftp    = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(ssh)

sftp.chdir (sTargetDir)

sftp.put (sOutputFilename, sOutputFilename)

ssh.close()
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443387/why-does-paramiko-hang-if-you-use-it-while-loading-a-module

Comment: Thanks. I didn't catch that one in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdness aside, I was just using import to compile the code.   Turning the script into a function seems like an unnecessary complication for this kind of application.

Searched for alternate means to compile and found:

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile("ProblemDemo.py")
```

This generated a pyc file that works as intended.
So the lesson learned is that import is not a robust way to compile python scripts.

Comment: but why would you want to compile your python script in the first place ?

Comment: It makes it easier to run from windows explorer and windows task scheduler.

Comment: I think the correct lesson learned is not to run lengthly or complex code during an import. Perhaps it is "legal" but surely not wise on numerous levels.

Comment: That is *a* lesson, but the real lesson here is it's corollary: <u>Don't use import to compile ad-hoc scripts</u>.   The objective for this question was successful compile.   

Noobs, like me, are told to use import to get the compiled file -- and it's worked on scores of scripts -- but it's bad advice.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what's going on here. Python is not a compiled language. You shouldn't run significant code while a module is being imported; wrap it in a function instead.

Answer (score 5):

That's indeed a bad idea to execute this kind of code at import time, although I am not sure why it hangs - it may be that import mechanism does something strange which interacts badly with paramiko (thread related issues maybe ?). Anyway, the usual solution is to implement the functionality into a function:

```
def my_expensive_function(args):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    my_expensive_functions(sys.args)
```

This　way, just importing the module will not do anything, but running the script will execute the function with the given arguments at command line.

Comment: +1 See detailed analysis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354248/5896591). I agree that minimizing code (waits in particular) that execute at `import` time will help to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a direct reason why, but **rarely do you ever** want to have "functionality" executed upon import.  Normally you should define a *class* or *function* that you then call like this:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.run()
```

The "global" code that you run in an import typically should be limited to imports, variable definitions, function and class definitions, and the like...

Comment: How would such a file be run from the OS?

This is not a library, I just imported it to get the pyc file generated.