# Paramiko hanging during authentication, when runned by dint of unittest runner

Tags: python, paramiko

Good day.

I have a strange problem with `paramiko` ssh client. `Connect paramiko` method hangs when it's called outside `unittest2` classes/functions and code was run by unittest runner.

There is a piece of code, where problem appears:

```py
import paramiko
import unittest2

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('172.18.67.10',
            username='root',
            password='secrete')
_, stdout, _ = ssh.exec_command('date')


class TestTest(unittest2.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
```

If I move `ssh.connect` into `TestTest` class or `setUpModule` function, connection will be successful. Also everything is OK when code is run by original Python interpreter.

When I try to debug `paramiko`, I figure out this problem inside `while True` loop in `paramiko/auth_handler.py:AuthHandler.wait_for_response method`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I observe the same behaviour, and it's not related to unittest. The bug appears when connect() is called in top level code during module import, not once the calls are moved into a function and not when entered in an interactive python session.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Paramiko hang if you use it while loading a module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443387/why-does-paramiko-hang-if-you-use-it-while-loading-a-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/450895/109807), it seems to be a thread-related bug in paramiko and can be avoided by not calling connect() during import.