# Paramiko does not connect

Tags: python, paramiko

I try to upload a file to a server via sftp using paramiko.

```
def send_file(server_, port_, user_, passwd_, file_, dir_):
    """
    :return:
    """
    try:
        transport = paramiko.Transport((server_, int(port_)))
        transport.connect(username=user_, password=passwd_)
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
        sftp.put(file_, dir_)
        sftp.close()
    except RuntimeError, err:
        print(str(err))
```

If I execute this function it just hangs (no response, no error messages), until the socket times out.

The credentials are correct, I tried them with sftp and ssh clients from the same machine and the same network. 
I also passed the Transport and connect values directly, no change.
The logs on the server_ don't show any connections when I use this function. 
The host key is in my known_hosts file.

The first statement in the try-block succeeds (I passed a string instead of an int to port_, this throws an exception), the second line seems to have problems.

What's the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE 1:

I tried this in ipython2 and it works. The function above is in a PyQt program and executed via

```
self.connect(self.b_upload, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onUpload)
```

Function onUpload:

```
def onUpload(self):
    file_, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog', 'Datei inklusive Pfad angeben: ')
    server_, port_, user_, passwd_, dir_ = ftpmod.read_config()
    ftpmod.send_file(server_, port_, user_, passwd_, file_, dir_)
```

Comment: Last Update: 2014-08-25. So: Nope.

Comment: It seems this is a bug(?) in paramiko, see [this][1] and [this][2] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443387/why-does-paramiko-hang-if-you-use-it-while-loading-a-module/450895#450895
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155890/paramiko-hanging-during-authentication-when-runned-by-dint-of-unittest-runner?lq=1

Comment: Please read link [2], it was still there in '12 and the problem is exact the same, a lock in the connect() thread. So, again: Nope.

Answer (score 0):

You can send via sftp, using `ssh.open_sftp`:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username, password)
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
ftp.put(localpath, remotepath)
ftp.close()
```

Comment: so... it works or not?) you can try also loading system host_keys: `ssh.load_system_host_keys()`

Comment: Please see my update. The problem is probably not a paramiko problem.

Comment: It is a paramiko problem. See my answer in comments in the original question.