# Paramiko hangs during connect()

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, paramiko

I'm trying to use paramiko to upload files to a remote EC2 server.

My app.py which primarily handles my tkinter GUI imports a custom lib.file_handler module that handles some functionality. That file_handler imports my lib.ssh_handler.py module. This module has a class that will handle my ssh requests. This works fine if I test my class within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` within the ssh_handler.py module. I know it's an issue with [spawning the additional thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443387/why-does-paramiko-hang-if-you-use-it-while-loading-a-module/450895#450895) within the imported module, I just don't know how to get around that as this module is so deep inside my app. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155890/paramiko-hanging-during-authentication-when-runned-by-dint-of-unittest-runner) suggests not calling connect() during import, which I don't think I'm doing as I have to initiate the class within the lib.file_handler.py before I use it. I don't want to always be connected to the remote server, only if I want to upload files, so I don't want paramiko.connect() within my app.py.

[Issue 104](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/104) has been open since 2012, but py3compat does not seem to be part of the module anymore.

Any input on how to solve this threading issue, or a good alternative to paramiko would be appreciated.
.

```
file_handler.py
from lib.ssh_handler import ssh_Handler

ssh = ssh_Handler()
ssh = ssh.upload_files()
```

```
ssh_hanlder.py
import paramiko

import lib.Secrets as Secrets

class ssh_Handler():
    """Handle interactions with a remote server"""
    def __init__(self, hostname=Secrets.hostname, user=Secrets.ssh_user, ssh_key=Secrets.ssh_key):
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
        self.ssh.connect(hostname=hostname, port=22, username=user, key_filename=ssh_key, allow_agent=False)
        self.storage_folder = '/path/to/storage'

03-18 14:02 paramiko.transport DEBUG    starting thread (client mode): 0xe42de650

03-18 14:02 paramiko.transport DEBUG    Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_3.4.0

03-18 14:02 paramiko.transport DEBUG    Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6

03-18 14:02 paramiko.transport INFO     Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.9p1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning Paramiko in favor of asyncssh. The working code is below. This also saves me from writing a recursive upload function.

```
import asyncio
import asyncssh

async def upload_directory(local_folder,
                           remote_folder=None,
                           hostname=Secrets.hostname,
                           user=Secrets.ssh_user,
                           ssh_key=Secrets.ssh_key):
    if remote_folder is None:
        remote_folder = 'folder/to/storage'
    async with asyncssh.connect(host=hostname,
                                username=user,
                                client_keys=ssh_key,
                                port=22) as conn:
        async with conn.start_sftp_client() as sftp:
            await sftp.put(localpaths=local_folder,
                           remotepath=remote_folder,
                           recurse=True)

try:
    local_path = 'path/to/directory'
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(upload_directory(local_path))
except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as error:
    print(error)
```