# How to use dynamic/runtime module imports with paramiko?

Tags: python, sftp, python-import, paramiko

I'm having problem with paramiko connection to SFTP server. Paramiko hangs during connection with dynamic module imports. What I've manage to investigate is that a problem is due to dynamic module imports (via `sys.path.append`)

My question has a lot in common with [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32875571/5309924) but in my scenario those 'hacks' simply don't work. Here is my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47756849/cannot-establish-connection-with-sftp-server-using-paramiko) since I though it was only STFP server connection problem. But in fact its import related problem.

My question is how to use dynamic/runtime module imports with paramiko?

```
  File "bin/sftp.py", line 13, in <module>
    import main
  File "/home/ufnal/Downloads/sftp_not_working/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ufnal/Downloads/sftp_not_working/main.py", line 13, in main
    with SftpClient(address, 22, root, username, None, keypath) as sftp:
  File "/home/ufnal/Downloads/sftp_not_working/src/sftp_client.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._connect()
  File "/home/ufnal/Downloads/sftp_not_working/src/sftp_client.py", line 84, in _connect
    pkey=self.pkey, username=self.username, password=self.password)
  File "/home/ufnal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1173, in connect
    self.start_client()
  File "/home/ufnal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 541, in start_client
    event.wait(0.1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 614, in wait
    self.__cond.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 359, in wait
    _sleep(delay)
```